# Closure Notation

Tags: notation, set-theory

Is there a way, using set comprehension, to denote the closure of a set under a particular operation?

For example, if $\mathrm{succ}(n)$ denotes the successor operator $n \mapsto n \cup \{n\}$, then the set $\mathbb N$ of natural numbers can be described as the closure of the set $\{0\}$ under the operator $\mathrm{succ}(n)$. But how can this be written using set comprehension? Would it be something like this?

$$\mathbb N = \{0\} \cup \{\mathrm{succ}(n):n\in\mathbb N\}$$

Or would I have to define, say, 
\begin{align*}
\mathbb N_0 &= \{0\}\\
\mathbb N_i &= \{\mathrm{succ}(n) : n\in \mathbb N_{i-1}\}\\
\mathbb N &= \bigcup_{i = 0}^\infty \mathbb N_i
\end{align*}

It seems odd using a union with indices to define the natural numbers though!

Comment: There's an archaic notation I quite like, but it's dated enough that you'd need to explain it if you're going to use it. Given any function $f$ (really any relation), we can use $*f$ to denote its transitive-reflexive closure, that is $*f:=\{\langle x,y\rangle:\forall A(x\in A\wedge \forall z(z\in A\Rightarrow f(z)\in A)\:.\Rightarrow y\in A)\}.$ Then your $f$-closure of a set $U$ is just the image of $U$ under $*f$; hence $\mathbb{N}=*\mathrm{succ}[\{0\}]$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just interested in defining $\mathbb{N}$, then the usual way to do it in ZF is via the axiom of infinity.  This axiom guarantees the existence of at least one set which is *inductive* which means that it contains the empty set and all successors of its own elements.  $\mathbb{N}$ (usually called $\omega$ in set theory) is then the intersection of all inductive sets, i.e. the smallest inductive set.  (You need at least one inductive set in order for the intersection to be well-defined.)

Comment: To be honest, I'm interested in finding a way, using set comprehension, to express the set $\{x, f(x), f(f(x)), f(f(f(x))), \dots\}$.

Comment: In that case I'd define a notation like $f^0(x)=x$ and $f^{n+1}(x)=f(f^n(x))$.  You can then write $\{f^n(x) : x \in \mathbb{N}\}$.

Comment: Thanks! Poor choice of example on my part perhaps, since $\mathbb N$ is defined axiomatically